# WPF: How do I style a column in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles

Ok, this is what I have so far:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350" 
    Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckboxColumn"
                  DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type s:Boolean}"
                 x:Key="items">
            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Number"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=.}"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckboxColumn}" />

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=.}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Even though I set the `CellTemplate` I still just get plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your data class that you are binding to, I can't tell for certain, but it appears that you may be binding to a non-Boolean type, and the binding is failing. Have you watched the Output window for binding exceptions?

Comment: I was just binding to the array defined as "<x:Array Type="{x:Type s:Boolean}"

Answer (score 0):

Duh. You can't have a `DisplayMemberBinding` and a `CellTemplate` for the same column.